# Can I create drop down list while using editor for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I create drop down list using data annotation?

I would like to achieve markup generated by

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.ContactType, Model.ContactTypeOptions)
```

to be set so I can use and it would generate dropdown list:

```
@Html.EditorForModel(Model)
```

My current model is:

```
public class ContactModel
    {
        public string ContactType { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> ContactTypeOptions
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){Text = "Options"}
        };
            }
        }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [MinLength(15)]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

**Updated**
I do not want to use partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [UIHint("_DropDownList")]
    public SelectList ContactType { get; set; }
}
```

Set (in your controller) `ContactType.Items` to be your list of options and `ContactType.SelectedValue` to be your initially selected value.

Then define a partial view **_DropDownList.cshtml**:

```
@model SelectList

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model)
```

You should then be able to use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ContactType)` and get your dropdown. And you can reuse it anywhere!

You might even get this behaviour out of the box nowadays when you do `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Property)` where `m.Property` is a `SelectList`. Not sure on that one.

If you're looking to just use `EditorForModel()` on your `ContactModel`, then you can just create an editor template called `ContactModel.cshtml` and do:

```
@model ContactModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContactType,
    new SelectList(Model.ContactTypeOptions, Model.ContactType))
```

Note that this should be called as `@Html.EditorForModel()` in a view already typed to a `ContactModel`- the object passed in as a parameter in the overload `EditorForModel(Object)` is for additional view data, *not* for the model object. `EditorForModel` always renders an editor template for the *current* view model.

Comment: If this doesn't do what you want, you need to be less vague.

Comment: sorry reading my comment does not make sense, I meant to say that I wanted to avoid using partial view and still have dropdown list rendering same way, your way is partial solution, which I do not like as I need to create partial view and still render it, also I need to modify existing code not to render dropdown list and use the partial view. This leads me to conclusion that it involves actually more work than creating full blown partial view. Thnx for trying anyway